# Visual Studio Code does not add function parentheses in JavaScript

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-editor

For example, I am writing

```
console.log
```

and press tab but Visual Studio Code does not add parentheses. When I look [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript), VSCode automatically adds open and close parentheses. However, it didn't work for me. How can I fix it? By the way, when I add the open parenthesis, it is adding the closed parenthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One setting which may help is to enable:

```
"javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
```

Search for

> Javascript > Suggest: Complete Function Calls
>
> ```
>  Complete Functions with their parameter signature.
> ```